# Why isn't it initializing it with all zeros as a static integers array?

Tags: c++

Why does the two arrays act differently in this case?

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char a[100] = {}; // all white spaces
    int b[100] = {} ; // all 0 
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << a[i] << "\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        cout << b[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Elements of `a` are in fact zeros. Try `cout << int(a[i])` and see for yourself. It's just that, apparently, a character with ASCII code 0 looks the same as a character with ASCII code 32 (aka "a space") when rendered on the console, and different from a character with ASCII code 48 (aka `'0'`)

Comment: Note that a null character `'\0'` is not the same thing as a space character  `' '`.

Comment: `char` is printed as characters. `'\0'` is interpreted as an end of string. Not sure how `cout` interprets when you try to print such a character.

Comment: Note that the character `'0'` is not the same thing as the `char` whose underlying integer representation is `0` (no single quotes). `a` is full of the latter.

Comment: @ALX23z -- `char` is printed as a **single** character; that's what it is. It is not a (C-style) string, so there is no "end of string" involved. It's only when you print an **array** of `char` that the notion of a nul terminator comes into play.

Answer (score 2):

It is indeed initialized to zeroes. Since it's a character array, zeros are just the `\0` character. Change that line from

```
cout << a[i] << "\n";
```

to

```
std::cout << '[' <<a[i] <<']' <<std::boolalpha<< (a[i] == '\0') << "\n";
```

help confirm what you expect is true.

Answer (score 0):

`char a[100] = {}; // all white spaces`

This line will initiate all elements to integer value 0, which when converted to it's ASCII equivalent is a null character.